# Display hidden row in asp.net mvc grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I have made grid with html table tag .in one of TD tag I have this code

```
<td>
     <a onclick="$('#lightBox').css('display','inline')"></a>
     <div style="display: none" id="lightbox">
    <%--<%Html.RenderAction("LightBox","PremiumSharingAdmin",new {historyId = premium.SharingPremiumHistoryID}); %>--%>
          <img  src="Storage/Images/<%=premium.SharingPremiumHistoryID %>.jpg" title="image" width="100" height="100"/>
              <div>
                  <textarea readonly="readonly"> 
                      <%= premium.Content %>
                  </textarea>
              </div>
              <div>
                  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<%= premium.SharingTitle %>"/>
              </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

These tag provide me some extra info from grid row that By default is hidden.

In other side I have Link tag that if user pressed that display that row.

but problem is that when I pressed it, it just show me the first record detail and when I press the others it show me the first row detail.

where is the problem guys ?

This is my whole ASPX view

```
<% foreach (var premium in Model)
   {%>
    <tr>
        <td style=" font-weight: bold;width: 130px;">

            <span ><%= premium.SharingTitle %></span>

        </td>
        <td style=" font-weight: bold;width: 130px;">
            <span ><%= premium.AddedDate.ConvertToPersianDate(true) %></span>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 130px;">
            <span> <%=  premium.IsSubmit %></span>


        </td>
         <td style="width: 130px;">
            <span> <%=  premium.ResturantName %></span>


        </td>
         <td style="width: 130px;">
            <span> <%=  premium.Content %></span>


        </td>
          <td style="width: 130px;">
           <div class="group">
                <a class="delete" href="<%= Url.Action("submit", "PremiumSharingAdmin", new {historyId = premium.SharingPremiumHistoryID}) %>" onclick="return confirm('آیا می‌خواهید این خبر را تایید کنید؟');">تایید</a>

            </div>


        </td>
        <td>
            <a onclick="$('#lightBox').css('display','inline')"></a>
            <div style="display: none" id="lightBox">
              <%--<%Html.RenderAction("LightBox","PremiumSharingAdmin",new {historyId = premium.SharingPremiumHistoryID}); %>--%>
                  <img  src="Storage/Images/<%=premium.SharingPremiumHistoryID %>.jpg" title="image" width="100" height="100"/>
                      <div>
                          <textarea readonly="readonly"> 
                              <%= premium.Content %>
                          </textarea>
                      </div>
                      <div>
                          <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="<%= premium.SharingTitle %>"/>
                      </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating invalid html by giving multiple `<div>` elements the same `id` attribute. `$('#lightBox').css('display','inline')` will return all elements with `id="lightbox"` but set the style of only the first.

Instead, use class names and use relative selectors. I also recommend you use [Unobtrusive Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and css, rather tan polluting your mark up with behavior.

Html

```
<td>
  <a href="#" class="toggle hidden">Show</a>
  <div class="lightbox">Some content to display</div>
</td>
```

CSS

```
.lightbox {
  display: none;
}
```

Script (at bottom of page)

```
  <script>
    $('.toggle').click(function () {
      if ($(this).hasClass('hidden')) {
        $(this).next('div').show();
        $(this).text('Hide');
      } else {
        $(this).text('Show');
        $(this).next('div').hide();
      }
      $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Side note: Using `RenderAction` to render the contents of the hidden div suggest the contents are large and/or you calling a service/database to get the contents. If that's the case you should be loading the contents on demand using ajax (unless your expecting the users to view the details of all rows)

Comment: Thank you @Stepehn Mucecke for your answer , but i have question what is .toggle class here?

Comment: `.toggle()` is a jquery method that toggles visibility between `display:block` and `display:none`. It just means you don't have to use `.show()` and `.hide()`  I also notice the `<a>` tag does not contain any content (e.g. "Show"). You could also adjust the script to toggle the text content from (say) "Show" to "Hide" on each click

Comment: Thank you for your kindness , but i have also another question ? I tried your code it s very good and is ok , but i should  press 3 times in link that show me the block . where is the problem  @Stephen Muecke ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean? Are you saying that it only works it you click it 3 times?

Comment: Yes , when  i click 3 times or some time more or less it show me the hidden block

Comment: That does make sense. Give me a moment to test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71356/discussion-between-salar-and-stephen-muecke).